# Is there any alternative to navigate to other pages making page look like gridview in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, gridview, layout, navigation

I am building a service app where features will be displayed as gridview in flutter, when tappeed/pressed on the specific tile on the grid, it should be navigated to another android page. Is there any way to do this using flutter? 
I tried using gridview, but unable to access independent tiles on the grid. when i tried using container and tried to used buttons then there will be pixel overflow. Is there any way to fix this?

```
      body: CustomScrollView(
  primary: false,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/lungs.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/cancer.jpg'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

**this is another method i tried using**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access index on each tapped `InkWell`, see below code, here a list of 100 items is generated, and each index is printed on `onTap: (){print('$index');},`

```
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
  // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
  // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
         crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
  // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
  print('$index');
     // use this line if you want to pass index position on the next page
             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          'YOUR_PAGE', arguments: '$index');
     //or if you don't want to pass anything use this
             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          'YOUR_PAGE');
       },
      child:Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
      )
      ),
    );
  }),
),
    ),
```

**How to fetch passed argument on next page?**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings 
    final var args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

To know more about [Pass arguments to a named route Read this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Output

[image]

Comment: How does it work for a specific tile? Main motive is navigation to other pages.